# CppCheck claims that a field is not used - while it is, in another file

Tags: qt-creator, static-analysis, cppcheck

I created a custom type, and put it into `command.h`

```
typedef struct 
{
    char name[16];
    int paramv[7];
    int paramc;
} command;
```

I'm using it in many other files, but not in `command.*`. Now I ran the CppCheck test with the QtCreator cppcheck plug-in. What I get is:

```
command.h:12: warning: Cppcheck: struct member 'command::name' is never used.
```

The same warning happens when I do

```
 cppcheck src --enable=all --suppress=missingIncludeSystem src/*
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hello I am a Cppcheck developer.

You should not check headers directly.

This warning is only written for non-included files. If you check command.h directly then command.h is not included so the warning is written.

So remove the src/* in your command. That option will mean that textfiles, images and whatever you have in src are checked.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove this option

> --check-config

It deactivates the normal checking, here is a [reference](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/cppcheck.1.html)

Comment: Even after removing `--check-config` there is no such a warning

Comment: 1.72, running Arch Linux

Comment: Before I do it: the problem is not that the standalone cppcheck is misbehaving. It misbehaves only when I use the CppCheck QtCreator plugin

Comment: OK, I see, by default cppcheck only scanned the `.c` files. After ordering it with the command from the updated OP, I can reproduce the same warning with standalone cppcheck. But still, I'm using the fields in another file, so I feel this warning is out of place